# Checking proof of uniqueness of ODEs using differential form of Gronwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I'm currently reading through Arnold's ODE book, and he briefly mentions in an exercise how the method for showing uniqueness of solutions to $\dot{x} = v(t, x)$ can be used to prove uniqueness of a solution in a phase space of any dimension (for reference, it is on page 38 of the book, problem 5). My proposed proof follows the answer outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444500/uniqueness-theorem-in-non-authonomous-ode) very closely, and I would appreciate a check for correctness. I am using the Euclidean norm here, although to my understanding this works for any equivalent norm (correct me if I am wrong).

Suppose $v:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lipschitz function. We want to show that the solution, if it exists, to the IVP
$$\dot{x} = v(x), \ x(t_0) = x_0$$
is unique. Since $v$ is Lipschitz, for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $|v(x) - v(y)| \leq K|x - y|$ for some real constant $K \geq 0$. Assume that $\varphi(t)$ solves the IVP over some neighbourhood of $t_0$, namely $(a, t_0] \cup [t_0, b)$, and consider any other solution $x(t)$ in this neighbourhood. Let $y(t) = x(t) - \varphi(t)$. Note that $y(t_0) = 0$, due to $x$ and $\varphi$ sharing the same initial condition. Then
$$\dot{y} = \dot{x}-\dot{\phi} = v(x) - v(\varphi) = v(\varphi +y)-v(\varphi)$$
So by the Lipschitz condition we have
$$|\dot{y}| = |v(\varphi+y)-v(\varphi)|\leq K|y|$$
Since $|y(t)|$ and $K$ are real-valued $C^1$ functions over $(t_0, b)$, we can apply Gronwall's inequality in differential form to get:
$$|y(t)| \leq |y(t_0)|e^{K(t-t_0)}=0$$
For $t \in (a, t_0]$, we note that $|y(\tau)|$ is also real-valued and $C^1$ over $\tau \in (t_0, 2t_0 - a)$, with the substitution $\tau = 2t_0 - t$. Then we can apply Gronwall again to find that $y(\tau) = 0$, i.e. $y(t) = y(2t_0 - \tau)=0$ for every $t \in (a, t_0]$. Hence, $y$ is identically zero over $(a, b)$, and we are done.

To my understanding, this proof, if correct, only proves uniqueness and doesn't say anything about existence, meaning some more work would need to be done for the usual full statement of uniqueness + existence.